# JS how to optimize function that finds the text value in gematria

Tags: javascript, performance

Hello guys i wrote this function code:

```
function gematria(text){
  var newText = text.toLowerCase(); // handle capital letters
  var startValue=0; //initialize value to zero
  for(let i=0 ; i<newText.length; i++){ // loop through every letter on the text
    let currentCharValue = newText.charCodeAt(i) - 96; // get the distance from the 'a'
    startValue +=currentCharValue;
  }
  return startValue
}

gematria("someText");
```

it works well but is there any way to do it more short? or better? how good is that code for doing the task?

Answer (score 2):

The shortest approach is to parse the character with a base of 36 and get the delta of `9` for summing.

```js
function gematria(text) {
    return [...text].reduce((s, c) => s + parseInt(c, 36) - 9, 0);
}

console.log(gematria("someText"));
```

Answer (score 1):

We can pre-compute a lookup table to make the function very fast, assuming that the accepted characters are known to be restricted to a range such as printable ASCII:

```js
const lut = Array.from(
  Array(128).keys(),
  index => String.fromCharCode(index).toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0) - 96
);

function gematria(text) {
  let startValue = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < text.length; ++i) {
    startValue += lut[text.charCodeAt(i)];
  }

  return startValue;
}

console.log(gematria("someText"));
```

Here's a [benchmark](https://jsperf.com/gematria-performance) comparing these three answers to the original implementation. On my Intel i7-9750H, running Windows 10, I get the following results:

#### Chrome 79.0.3945.117:

- [Mine](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/236001/73672): 57,128,914 ops/sec (fastest)
- [Original](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/235998/73672): 37,709,334 ops/sec (34% slower)
- [Jonas Wilms](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/235999/73672): 10,484,026 ops/sec (82% slower)
- [Nina Scholz](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/236000/73672): 2,377,434 ops/sec (96% slower)

#### Firefox 72.0.2:

- [Original](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/235998/73672): 65,230,557 ops/sec (fastest)
- [Mine](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/236001/73672): 58,459,179 ops/sec (10% slower)
- [Jonas Wilms](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/235999/73672): 3,964,879 ops/sec (94% slower)
- [Nina Scholz](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/236000/73672): 2,892,339 ops/sec (96% slower)

#### Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0:

- [Mine](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/236001/73672): 8,118,924 ops/sec (fastest)
- [Original](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/235998/73672): 5,840,381 ops/sec (29% slower)
- [Nina Scholz](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/236000/73672): 470,844 ops/sec (94% slower)
- [Jonas Wilms](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/235999/73672): 422,330 ops/sec (95% slower)

I did optimize this for V8, so I'm not surprised that SpiderMonkey turned out to favor the original answer, but best 2 out of 3 isn't bad in my opinion.

Comment: How about { a: 1, b: 2 ... } ... that could be faster.

Comment: @JonasWilms it's not.

Comment: Does your measurement include building up the lut?

Comment: @JonasWilms no, because that only needs to be done once. That's also why it doesn't include defining the functions.

Comment: But if the function is only run once ... might be worth calculating runs = (other_time - lut_time) / run_time ;)

Comment: @JonasWilms if the function is only run once then there's no point discussing performance at all. Feel free to calculate it yourself if you care, that's beyond the scope of the question, and my interest for that matter.

Answer (score -1):

Shorter:

```
  const gematria = text => [...text].reduce((s, c) => s + c.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0) - 96, 0);
```

Better: I don't know. Your code is totally fine.

Comment: …and also different in its handling of multi-byte unicode characters.

Comment: You have missed `toLowerCase` part

Comment: @yury whoops, fixed ...

Comment: why not `[...text.toLowerCase()]`?

Comment: @nina I have no idea ...

Comment: @bergi oh, nice catch. Not sure if a +2000 years old technique needs to support emojis though ;)

Comment: Oh, I had no idea what [gematria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gematria) means… Yeah, hardly matters :-)